# Retrieve latest few records from the table based on one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the latest few records from the table based on grouping one of the column values which is not a primary key. This means there will be more than one row for a specific column value which I want the results grouped on. The data base is MySQL based.

Table Metrics schema

```
TestID BuildId TestResult  TestMetrics
a123     b345     Pass       metric1
a234     b234     Fail       metric2
a345     b345     Fail       metric3
a456     b123     Fail       metric4
a567     b234     Pass       metric5
```

E.g. I want to retrieve the latest two build data from the above table.

Expected Result:

```
TestID BuildId TestResult  TestMetrics
a123     b345     Pass       metric1
a345     b345     Fail       metric3
a234     b234     Fail       metric2
a567     b234     Pass       metric5
```

TestID is the primary key. Now I would like to retrieve the latest 2 build information from the table and display the result ordered by buildId in the descending order (latest).

What I have right now is

```
select * from Metrics as m inner join 
   (select n.BuildId from Metrics as n group by n.BuildId order by n.BuildId desc limit 2)
on m.BuildId = n.BuildId
order by BuildId desc
```

This looks highly inefficient as the table contains huge amount of metrics data. There are where clauses where I can filter on based on a specific dev branch the test ran.

Is there a better way to achieve the expected results?

Comment: what happened to b123, also doyou have mysql 8.x by any chance?

Comment: The latest two which means b345 and b234 in that order. I consider b123 in this case as old and want to ignore it.

Comment: I understand what you are pointing at. I modified my current  query in the question and that is why you won't see b123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can achieve that by using the window function [row_number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

e.g

```sql
with mm as 
  (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by buildid order by TestID desc) as nrow from metrics) 
select * 
from mm 
where nrow <=2 
order by buildId, nrow;
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Will run more tests on the real data and update the result here.

Comment: TT his still would not remove b123

Comment: @nbk no it would not because nrow <= 2 I believe. I have not tested it yet but will do over weekend.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a subquery with the MAX function to find the latest `BuildId` for all the `TestMetrics` values, and then join the result with the `Metrics` table to get the corresponding `TestID` and `TestResult` values.

In code, you should have

```
SELECT m.TestID, m.BuildId, m.TestResult, m.TestMetrics
FROM Metrics m
JOIN (
  SELECT TestMetrics, MAX(BuildId) AS latestBuildId
  FROM Metrics
  GROUP BY TestMetrics
  ORDER BY latestBuildId DESC
  LIMIT 2
) latest ON m.TestMetrics = latest.TestMetrics AND m.BuildId = latest.latestBuildId
ORDER BY m.BuildId DESC;
```

Comment: did you test your query? https://dbfiddle.uk/53lyOnO6

Comment: @nbk OP said they needed latest 2

Comment: he wants for every build the latest two, but still he doesn't explain where build id b123 went

Comment: The query returns only two rows but I want all the rows of the same build id for the latest two build ids.

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for https://dbfiddle.uk/tKzwDfSJ

Answer (score 0):

Ervis's answer pointed me in the right direction despite not being exactly what I was looking for. So posting this post as the answer as the correct solution in the context of the question.

I wanted the window function to generate the same number for the rows with the same buildId and that is where DENSE_RANK() comes into picture. Below is the exact solution I wanted.

```
with mm as 
  (select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by BuildId desc) as nrow from metrics) 
select * 
from mm 
where nrow <=2 
order by buildId, nrow;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).